# Slidingbar .js animation not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I just built a sliding top panel for a website which is running on wordpress. Therefore I've added the bar into the header by using a hook point. I use a very simple custom.js (mostly copied together from different sources), so that the bar will "slide down" (=appear) on first click and "slide up" (=disappear) on the second click. For some reasons, this animation is not running smoothly. While it is a little bit too fast (which I could easily change by increasing the speed duration), the animations also seems to be laggy. I bet, I oversee something important, cause I am not used to jQuery/Javascript. Exists there some of code snippets to make the transition more smoothly?

Java-Script Markup:

```
// Slidingbar initialization
var tgslidingbar_state = 0;

// Clicking
jQuery( '.tg-toggle-wrapper' ).click( function(){
var $tgslidingbar = jQuery ( this ).parents( '#tgslidingbar-area').children( '#tgslidingbar' );


//Expand
if ( tgslidingbar_state === 0 ) {
$tgslidingbar.slideDown( 340, 'easeOutQuad' );
jQuery( '.tg-toggle-wrapper' ).addClass( 'open' );
tgslidingbar_state = 1;

 //Collapse
 } else if( tgslidingbar_state == 1 ) {
 $tgslidingbar.slideUp(340,'easeOutQuad');
 jQuery( '.tg-toggle-wrapper' ).removeClass( 'open' );
 tgslidingbar_state = 0;
 }   
 });
```

HTML-Markup:

```
<div id="tgslidingbar-area" class="tgslidingbar-area">

<div style="display: none;" id="tgslidingbar">
<div class="containertop">


Slidingbar Content Here!

</div></div>

<div class="tg-toggle-wrapper"><a class="tg-toggle" href="#"></a>    

</div></div>
```

With this markup the sliding bar does slide down and up. For example, I've added a google maps into the sliding bar, when I've noticed that the bar is laggy. Could this be a reason for the laggy animations, too, cause google maps just loads when the bar opens? I also realized the "easeOutQuad" property in the copied snippet animations and searched for this on the web. It seems to be a popular jQuery library for animations. Up to now I do not have included this library into my websites, maybe thats the cause?

Kind Regards from Germany!

Comment: change the type of slide animation from `easeOutQuad` to your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied some modification on the code.

I use query’s animate function.

A initial display property of #tgslidingbar was changed to ‘block’

added ‘padding’ on container top class and removed ‘padding’ on tgslidingbar class.

https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/cn49ubr6/

[html]

```
  <div style="display:block;height:0" id="tgslidingbar">
```

[JS]

```
var tgslidingbar_state = 0;
var $tgslidingbar = jQuery('#tgslidingbar');
var nHeight = $tgslidingbar.get(0).scrollHeight;


// Handle the slidingbar toggle click
jQuery('.tg-toggle-wrapper').click(function() {


  //Expand
  if (tgslidingbar_state === 0) {
    $tgslidingbar.animate({
      'height': nHeight
    }, 340, function() {
      jQuery('.tg-toggle-wrapper').addClass('open');
      tgslidingbar_state = 1;
    });
    ......
```

Comment: Yeah, you did it! The animations is now smooth!!! :-)

one left thing occurring with this solution: It seems the height of the slidingbar-area now adapts to full height of the browser. I just checked and on firefox nightly for example the height of the slidingbar-area is too big, so the icon for slideup is not in content view anymore + no scrolling available on my site. Is there a way to adapt the height just to the height of the divs within the sidebar, since the divs flex_column_half are displayed side by side on larger screens? Anyway, you rock! :-)

Comment: Sorry,, i don't understand an additional question. can't you move a scrollbar?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading communication. I investigated your awesome js. further. Firstly the sliding bar is sticked to my header, which is floating. Now the browser viewport automatically jumps to top again when you click the expanding button. Second thing is, when I resize the window, the sliding bar height does not adapt so the content is shown properly, cause the flex_column divs break under a certain point. Both things are not so bad (top jumping does not influence the functionality & normal user does not resize window) but maybe there is also a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some different options.

**first,**

Instead, use jquery's animate function.
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

sample code : https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/jo5vd2ob/

**second.**

you can use css transition.
http://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/qy1ummx6/1/

[css]

```
.box {     
float: left; 
/* you can use other ease effect. ease-in, ease-out, ease-in-out */   
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; 
overflow: hidden;
}

.height {
background-color: red;
width: 300px;
max-height: 0px;
}
.change {
   max-height: 500px;
}
```

[JS]

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('change');
});
```

Comment: Hey,

I gave both options a quick try but wasnt able to get anyone of them to work cause I am very new to JS. I dont even know how to modify your jsfiddle solution to my markup. Just wanted to say thanks, I need a little bit rest now. I will come back to you later today or on the weekend in the case I am still unable to get them working after spending more time on your solution:)

Comment: Bis zum nächsten Mal :-)

Comment: Hi nigayo, it seems you are able to speak german, while the discussion is public I will stick to english anyway. The best solution for me and the mark up would be the first option. Here is what I've tried in the JS file: 

`//Expand 
if ( tgslidingbar_state === 0 ) { $tgslidingbar.animate({height: "toggle"}, 5000 ); jQuery( '.tg-toggle-wrapper' ).addClass( 'open' ); tgslidingbar_state = 1;`

I did the same thing for collapse. The slideingbar does scroll but is jumping at the very beginning. It seems there is no animation in this area at all.

Greetings from Trier!

Comment: Hi nigayo, 

sorry for the double post. I was able to find the reason why the bar is jumping at the very beginning. The animation object #tgslidingbar, which is a child of the whole #slidingbar-area had paddings to the top and the bottom. After I eliminate them, the bar is sliding completely but still a little bit laggy.

Comment: Can you show your code? (as jsfiddle link).

I wrote a code for your help as below.

-> https://jsfiddle.net/nigayo/jo5vd2ob/

Comment: Hi, for sure:
https://jsfiddle.net/uh5hw3ak/

Strangely enough the animations on fiddle is smoother, but you can realize my problem, first and foremost when you slide down for the **very first time** - Rather the (first) slide down animation is the problem than the slideup animation on my site. The slideup is always smoother. Maybe the problem lays somehow in the implementation of google maps. Your code worked well after changing the height to "toggle" and insert jQuery instead of $, but didn't solve the laggy animation. Thank you so much for your efforts anyway, I appreciate that! :-)

Comment: @DoUtDes Hey! I added another answer! check it.